# Url rewrite isn't working with new category

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, categories

I have a new category in my Magento site, and I cant seem to get the category url-rewrite to work correctly.  I set up the URL key as *housecalls* and I cant seem to figure out how to get it to the page.

I want this:
http://www.docjohnson.com/housecalls
But it gives me a 404 error.

I tried a few variations, and nothing brings me to it.

Comment: Dis will help you https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-administration/664-fixing-url-rewrites-with-magento

Comment: You probably need to reindex data to generate the new  urls

Comment: I did all that - still 404 error when I go to that link

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear cache management and reindex managenment from system->cache management and system->reindex managenment

Hope it will help